# cascading dropdown for dynamically added row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched everywhere but can't find a guide for cascading dropdowns (JQuery) in dynamically added rows. These are rows that are added at runtime by the user using Jquery. There are 2 dropdowns, one I am hoping can be dependent on the other.

The code in the below link works because we know there is only one SelectedLocation. In mine however there will be >=1 (as a user can add as many rows as they like).

[Cascading dropdowns MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640196/cascading-dropdowns-mvc-3)

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The code below works for the first added row. Every row that is added after that it doesn't work. Clearly this is because the ID for the relevant elements (Selecteduserid and Selectedrate) is the same as that in the first row

My partial view for each added row:

```
@model authentication.ViewModels.LineViewModel


@using authentication.WebUI.Helpers
<tr class="editorRow  ">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineViewModels"))
    {
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selecteduserid, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "FullName"), "--Select--", new { id = "Selecteduserid" })</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedcatid, new SelectList(Model.categories, "CatID", "FullCat"), "--Select--", new { style = "width: 120px" })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingDate)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Venue, new { @class = "smalltext" })</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedrate, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"---select", new { id = "Selectedrate" })</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedhours, new SelectList(new[] { "0.5", "1", "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "3.5", "4", "4.5", "5", "5.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "10", "10.5", }))</td>  
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Miles)</td>    
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelCost)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParkingCost)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comments, new { @class = "bigtext" })</td>

        <td>
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
        </td>


    }
</tr>
```

JS that adds row and enables cascading dropdown on first row

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Claims/BlankEditorRow',
        cache: false,
        //async: true,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(html);
            $('#editorRows .date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
            $('#Selecteduserid').change(function () {
                var Selecteduserid = $(this).val();
                if (Selecteduserid != null && Selecteduserid != '') {
                    $.getJSON('/Claims/Rates', { locId: Selecteduserid },
            function (rate) {

                var RateSelect = $('#Selectedrate');
                RateSelect.empty();
                $.each(rate, function (index, rate) {
                    RateSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: rate.value,
                        text: rate.text
                    }));
                });
            });

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

So my question is how do I work the IDs such that this code will work?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the code you have referenced wouldn't work for dynamically added rows.  What issue are you having with it?

Comment: thanks I have added more detail above about the issue I am having

Comment: @mattbloke - did you ever get an answer to this? I am having the same issue. If I POST my model and there is an error when it is re-displayed the 2nd cascaded dropdown is not set correctly.